# Getting the error "Cannot add or remove items from Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty" in Json.net

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

So I'm trying to control deserialization by reading a json object as a JObject, deleting some fields, and then deserializing it again to my target object using [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json). The problem is, any time I try to delete a field, I get the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException'
>   occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot add or remove items from
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.

Here's my (simplified, but still causing the error) code:

```
JToken token = (JToken)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(fileName));

foreach (JToken inner in token["docs"])
{
    if (inner["_id"] != null)
        inner["_id"].Remove();

    MyObject read = new MyObject();
    JsonConvert.PopulateObject(inner.ToString(), read);
    Values.Add((MyObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(inner.ToString(), typeof(MyObject)));
}
```

The json is a very large file where the docs array contains many elements as follows (again simplified for clarity):

```
{
    "docs": [
        {
            "Time": "None",
            "Level": 1,
            "_id": "10208"              
        },
        {
            "Time": "None",
            "Level": 1,
            "_id": "10209"
        }
    ]
}
```

Alternatively if there's a better way to deserialize JSON to a specific type, but still ignoring additional fields, that would be a fine alternative.

Comment: Please post your JSON

Comment: I'm not sure it's relevant, because we know that inner["id"] isn't null, but I've put it onto the question anyway.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Assuming `Values` is a `List<MyObject>` and your `MyObject` class looks like this:

```
class MyObject
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
}
```

you can replace all that code with the following to get the result you want:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
Values = JToken.Parse(json)["docs"].ToObject<List<MyObject>>();
```

This works because Json.Net will ignore missing properties by default.  Since the `MyObject` class does not contain an `_id` property to deserialize into, you don't need to jump through hoops trying to remove it from the JSON.

**Explanation of why `Remove()` didn't work**

`JToken.Remove()` removes a `JToken` from its parent.  It is legal to remove a `JProperty` from its parent `JObject`, or to remove a child `JToken` from a `JArray`.  However, you cannot remove the value from a `JProperty`.  A `JProperty` must always have exactly one value.

When you ask for `token["_id"]` you get back the *value* of the `JProperty` called `_id`, not the `JProperty` itself.  Therefore you will get an error if you try to call `Remove()` on that value.  To make it work the way you are doing, you'd need to use `Parent` like this:

```
if (inner["_id"] != null)
    inner["_id"].Parent.Remove();
```

This says "Find the property whose name is `_id` and give me the value.  If it exists, get that value's parent (the property), and remove it from its parent (the containing `JObject`)."

A more straightforward way to do it is to use the `Property()` method to access the property directly.  However, this method is only available on `JObject`, not `JToken`, so you would either need to change the declaration of `inner` to a `JObject` or cast it:

```
foreach (JObject inner in token["docs"].Children<JObject>())
{
    JProperty idProp = inner.Property("_id");
    if (idProp != null)
        idProp.Remove();
    ...
}
```

Lastly, as mentioned in the comments, if you're using C# 6 or later you can shorten the code a bit using the null-conditional operator:

```
    inner.Property("_id")?.Remove();
```

Comment: Thank you, it's very useful to know that Json.net ignores extra properties. That said, I'd still love to know why I'm not able to Remove() the fields.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly the explanation I was looking for!

Comment: Shorter version: inner.SelectToken("_id")?.Parent.Remove();

Comment: Man, it's impressive how many things in cs add a lot of unnecessarily complexities :( I'd never imagine it would be a nightmare to remove a json property/token/whatever...

Comment: @Jas "nightmare" is probably too strong of a word.  The issue isn't really with c# here, but rather just quirks of the Json.Net library.

Comment: @BrianRogers that's what I mean - my cs stands for computer science, not csharp lol. Json should be super straightforward. I've been working in Java, Js, and pythoin projects for over a year - last week I had to start a csharp one, and it is pretty annoying to deal with all the things we have to do with json.net to do a simple task like an element removal :(

Answer (score -3):

Based on brillian answer from Brian, you can do simply this in your case:

```
var inner_id = inner["_id"] as JProperty;
if (inner_id != null)
  inner_id.Remove();
```

Comment: Sorry, this won't work. As I stated in my answer, using the indexer syntax will give you the value of the `JProperty`, not the `JProperty` itself. The value will never be a `JProperty` because `JProperties` cannot directly contain other `JProperties`. So when you try to cast the `inner["_id"]` expression to `JProperty` as you are doing here, it will always be `null` and thus `Remove()` will never be called. See for yourself: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EkTU4o

Comment: Ah... This is confusing, but I have got it now. Suddenly the code in my project works as intended! Even though my answer is wrong, I let it stand as an example of how not to do it...