# How to iterate through a nested json and check if a key is present in a given list or not using C#

Tags: c#, json

I want to iterate through a nested json and check if a key is present in a given list. If the key is not present in the list I want to remove the key value pair from the json.

Here is my code. I want to remove all the keys which are not present in the the uniqueList list.

```
 public static void DiffConfigMain()
        {
            JToken left = JToken.Parse(@"{
                ""TEST JSON"" : ""JSON"",
                ""JSON"":{
                    ""EX"":[
                                {
                                    ""ID"":0,
                                    ""EX-S"":
                                    {
                                    ""EX-1"":0,
                                    ""EX-2"":0
                                    }          
                                }
                           ]
                    }}");
            JToken right = JToken.Parse(@"{
                ""TEST JSON"" : ""JSON"",
                ""JSON"":{
                    ""EX"":[
                                {
                                    ""ID"":0,
                                    ""EX-S"":
                                    {
                                    ""EX-1"":0,
                                    ""EX-2"":4
                                    }          
                                }
                           ]
                    }}"); ;
            var jdp = new JsonDiffPatch();
            var diff1 = jdp.Diff(left, right);
            Console.WriteLine("----diff using JsonDiffPatchDotNet----");
            Console.WriteLine($"{diff1} \n");

if (diff1 != null)
            {
                var diff1PatchOutput = jdp.Patch(left, diff1).ToString();
                var diffPlatformIds = ((JObject)JObject.Parse(diff1.ToString())["JSON"]["EX"]).Properties().Select(p => p.Name);
                var platfromJson = JObject.Parse(diff1PatchOutput)["JSON"]["EX"].Cast<JObject>();
                var changedItems = platfromJson.Where(plat => diffPlatformIds.Contains(((JValue)plat["ID"]).ToString()));
                var FinalJson = JObject.Parse(@"{""JSON"": {""EX"":[] } }");
                FinalJson["JSON"]["EX"] = Minify(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(changedItems).ToString());
                var formatChange = FinalJson.ToString();
                string final = FinalJson.ToString().Replace("\"[", "[").Replace("]\"", "]").Replace($"\\", "");
                Console.WriteLine("------------- Final OUTPUT -----------");
                Console.WriteLine($"{final} \n");
                var dict = JsonHelper.DeserializeAndFlatten(diff1.ToString());
                HashSet<string> uniqueList = new HashSet<string>();
                
                foreach (var kvp in dict)
                {
                    int i = kvp.Key.LastIndexOf(".");
                    string key = kvp.Key.Substring(kvp.Key.Substring(0, kvp.Key.LastIndexOf(".")).LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                    var keynames = key.Substring(0, key.LastIndexOf("."));
                    foreach(var split in (kvp.Key.Split("."))){
                        uniqueList.Add(split);
                    }
                    uniqueList.Add(keynames);
                    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
                }
                var backJs = JObject.Parse(final);
                var backJsT = JObject.Parse(final);
                Console.WriteLine("----Unique List -----");
                foreach (var i in uniqueList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }

                foreach (var cc  in backJs)
                {
                    if (!uniqueList.Contains(cc.Key))
                    {
                        
                        Console.WriteLine(cc.Key);
                        backJsT.Remove(cc.Key);
                        //Console.WriteLine(backJsT);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(backJsT);
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Diff failed - (Same jsons) -   or Invalid json inputs left and rigth !");
            }
        }
```

```
public class JsonHelper
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, object> DeserializeAndFlatten(string json)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);
            FillDictionaryFromJToken(dict, token, "");
            return dict;
        }

        private static void FillDictionaryFromJToken(Dictionary<string, object> dict, JToken token, string prefix)
        {
            switch (token.Type)
            {
                case JTokenType.Object:
                    foreach (JProperty prop in token.Children<JProperty>())
                    {
                        FillDictionaryFromJToken(dict, prop.Value, Join(prefix, prop.Name));
                    }
                    break;

                case JTokenType.Array:
                    int index = 0;
                    foreach (JToken value in token.Children())
                    {
                        FillDictionaryFromJToken(dict, value, Join(prefix, index.ToString()));
                        index++;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    dict.Add(prefix, ((JValue)token).Value);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private static string Join(string prefix, string name)
        {
            return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) ? name : prefix + "." + name);
        }
    }
```

**current output json and unique list respectively**

```
{
  "JSON": {
    "EX": [{"ID":0,"EX-S":{"EX-1":0,"EX-2":4}}]
  }
}

JSON
EX
EX-
EX-2
```

Now I want to iterate through the nested json (it should iterate through all the nests) and keep checking if the key is present in the list. Here since EX-1 and ID are not present I want to delete that particular key value pairs("EX-1":0 and "ID":0) from the json.

Thanks in Advance !

> EDIT: simplified question and Added JsonHelper class

How to iterate through all the keys of a heavily nested json?

Comment: Can you explain what your use-case is for this? It seems like what you're actually after is some method of transforming JSON documents, like JUST or JDT.

Comment: This is for a custom use-case where the final output should contain only the diff between the original and edited json while preserving the hierarchy. moreover the keys ID should be present in the output json even though if its not edited.

Comment: try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898727/getting-the-error-cannot-add-or-remove-items-from-newtonsoft-json-linq-jpropert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DescendantsAndSelf` while materializing it first (by calling `ToList`), and then just remove each property.

- Note: I'm addressing your question rather than your own code, which much of it is not necessary to accomplish what you're after.

[Full Demo Here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vVrnUA)

Example json:

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: {
        d: 1,
        e: 2
    }
}
```

Example list:

```
[a, b, c, e]
```

Expected result:

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: {
        e: 2
    }
}
```

Code:

```
void TraverseAndRemove()
{
   var keys = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "e" };
   var json = @"
   {
     a: 1,
     b: 2,
     c: {
       d: 1,
       e: 2
     }
   }";
   var root = JObject.Parse(json);
   var descendants = root.DescendantsAndSelf().ToList();
   foreach (var d in descendants)
   {
       var jProp = d as JProperty;
       if (jProp != null && !keys.Contains(jProp.Name))
           jProp.Remove();
   }
}
```